# How to subtract variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that can be used to enter data and keep records but can't figure out how to subtract two variables, I am relatively new to coding, thanks for any help :

```
ans = str
gram = int
bprice = int
sprice = int
totalg = int
balance = int
totalc = int
timesb = int
timess = int
profit = balance - totalc
while ans != "buy" or "sell" or "enter" or "check":
     print ("Would you like to Buy, Sell, Enter Variables or Check Records ?")
     ans = input()
if ans == "buy" :
     print ("How many grams?")
     gram = input()
     print ("How much did you pay for it?")
     bprice = input()
     totalg = int(totalg) + int(gram)
     balance = int(balance) - int(bprice)
     totalc = int(totalc) + int(bprice)
     timesb = timesb + 1
if ans == "sell" :
     print ("How many grams?")
     gram = input()
     print ("How much did you sell it for?")
     sprice = input()
     totalg = int(totalg) - int(gram)
     balance = int(balance) + int(sprice)
     timess = timess + 1
if ans == "enter" :
     print ("What is the starting balance?")
     balance = input()
if ans == "check" :
     print ("Balance = £",balance)
     print ("Total cost = £",totalc)
     print ("Stock left = ",totalg,"g")
     print ("Profit = £",profit)
     print ("Times bought = ",timesb)
     print ("Times sold = ",timess)
```

Comment: input() returns a string, you need to convert this to a float or an integer.

Comment: The first 9 lines make no sense.

Comment: i tried doing                        profit = int(balance) - int(totalc)            but it didnt work

Comment: Your while loop will never end either, its unclear exactly what issue you're having, what does it currently do that you dont expect?

Comment: do you want to get balance and totalc from user ?

Comment: Your `while` test doesn't do what you think it does. It is always `True`. Use `in` not `==`.

Comment: balance should be from user but totalc shouldn't

Comment: eventually i want to make the program edit numbers on a text file so it would keep records but im unsure on how to do that as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your variables otherwise you will have errors. Be careful on your while condition you should put "and" not or. Here is a working code for the buy condition :

```
ans = str
gram = 20
bprice = int
sprice = int
totalg = 20
balance = 10
totalc = 20
timesb = 0
timess = int
profit = balance - totalc

while ans != "buy" and ans!="sell" and ans!="enter" and ans!="check":
     print ("Would you like to Buy, Sell, Enter Variables or Check Records?")
     ans = input()
if ans == "buy" :
     print ("How many grams?")
     gram = input()
     print ("How much did you pay for it?")
     bprice = input()
     totalg = totalg + int(gram)
     balance = balance - int(bprice)
     totalc = int(totalc) + int(bprice)
     timesb = timesb + 1
```

Comment: that works thank you, i want to save the data to a text file so the variables dont reset each time the program is opened

Comment: Here is how you write in a txt file in python : file = open('test_file.txt','w') ;
var = 'hello world';
file.write(var) ;
file.close() ; For more information look up this [link](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)